# question regarding setting actions for a search box

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to create a function for a search box that when nothing is type into the field and the user hit enter it would perform an action. When the user enter something and hit enter it would perform a different action.

As of now the search box is working when the user type an input and press enter, but when the search box is blank and the user press enter nothing happens. Can someone look at my code and see why this is happening.

```
handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 13 && e.target.value !== '') {
        this.props.actions.searchListings(e.target.value);
    } else if (e.keyCode === 13 && e.target.value === '') {
        this.props.actions.setListingsPage(0);
    }
};
```

So this action works

> this.props.actions.searchListings(e.target.value);

but this action isn't working

> this.props.actions.setListingsPage(0);

Comment: Since [this](https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/psn48u5b/) works fine, is it possible the error is in related code elsewhere?

Comment: Is this a uncaught 'TypeError'? `e.target.value` is of type `String` but the argument passed to the function in the second `if-statement` is of type `Number`??   From what we have, the problem appears to lie with the function called rather than the code itself.

Comment: `this.props.actions.setListingsPage(0);` works for the other section of the code so i know it's has nothing to do with the function. I don't know if i'm setting `e.target.value` right. Basically if the user leave the serahc box blank and press enter this action should occur `this.props.actions.setListingsPage(0);` .

Comment: Please add `console.log()` calls to make sure the second if block actually runs.

Comment: This would be possible that you have another if statement in your `this.props.actions.setListingsPage()` that checks the passed arg value. so this may be possible that you're returning `false` since `0` is a false value.